# Debugging minidumps from Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone, crash-reports, minidump

I've got a minidump from Windows Phone crash report. It contains a managed exception. I can open the minidump in VS2013, but when trying to debug as managed, I get the following:

> Unable to managed debug this minidump. The matching version of
>   System.Runtime.dll could not be found on the Microsoft symbol server
>   or on the symbol search path.  Make sure the computer has internet
>   access so the dll can be downloaded from Microsoft.

Additionally, in Output window, there's the following:

> SYMSRV:  e:\symbols\System.Runtime.dll\536B47F4a000\System.Runtime.dll not found
>
> SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/System.Runtime.dll/536B47F4a000/System.Runtime.dll not found
>
> http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: Symbols not found on symbol server.

I have Microsoft Symbol Server enabled. There's a copy of System.Runtime.dll under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1`

Any ideas, please? Is there an alternative symbol server with WP8 symbols? I've tried excluding System.Runtime.dll from the list of modules to load symbols for; doesn't help.

**EDIT: The bug report is [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1407487). If you're suffering from the same, please go there and place a "I can [reproduce] too".**

Comment: I remember this happened for other .NET runtimes as well. IIRC, asking someone from Microsoft for help (perhaps open a bug) caused Microsoft to publish the symbols. Look for similar questions tagged [tag:windbg], I could not find a related answer immediately.

Comment: What does `lmv` give you as version number? Is it a beta/preview build or something?

Comment: The crash minidumps come from user phones. I have numerous minidumps, none of them debug (last time I've checked). All those users can't be on a beta build. What's lmv?

Comment: Oh, I assumed you do the analysis in WinDbg. `lmv` is a command there to display verbose information about a DLL.

Comment: I'm working in Visual Studio 2013. The DLL build identifier (is that the version you want?) is in the message that's quoted in the question text.